# How can i redirect a webpage to another webpage permanently through cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

How can redirect a webpage to another webpage permanently using cPanel

Ex:

> www.abc/contactUs.php

redirect to

> www.abc/contactus.php

Answer (score 0):

1. open **Redirects** link in the Domains section.
   [image]
2. In the Type, section chooses if you want to create a Permanent (301) or Temporary (302) redirect. Generally, any redirects will be Permanent (which is the default).

[image]

3. In the next drop-down choose the domain you want to forward.
   [image]
4. If you want to redirect a specific file (such as info.html) enter it in the blank forward slash '/' field.
   [image]
5. In the Redirects to box enter the domain you want the traffic redirected to.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can i redirect a page in same domain

Comment: If you want to redirect to a page in your domain check step **4**